# PHP evaluation in rule to detect empty view

Tags: 7, views, rules

I have a newsletter going out each day that lists the most recent articles. The newsletter is using a template file that I have created with a view inside. Everything seems to be working fine, but the problem is if it's a holiday or a weekend. The newsletter still goes out, but it's empty. It would be great to run the rule only when there is actually new content in the view.

I saw in the rule preferences there is a "PHP Evaluation" section and am wondering if it's at all possible to have a rule that looks at the specific view to see if it's empty. If it is, then it doesn't run.

Here is my current rule setup where I am testing this out every 10 minutes to see if it will work:

[image]

UPDATE: I found [someone](https://www.drupal.org/node/2103817#comment-8887629) who was able to make it work, but I am having issues making it work for me as I do not know much PHP.

```
function _my_notifier_is_view_empty($viewname, $display_id = null) {
  $view = views_get_view($viewname, $viewargs = array());
  if (! is_null($display_id)) {
    $view->set_display($display_id);
  }
  $view->get_total_rows = TRUE;
  $view->set_arguments($viewargs);
  $view->execute();
  if ($view->total_rows > 0) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
return !_my_notifier_is_view_empty('job_type_c_list');
```

Basically what in this text do I need to customize?

Comment: I think you would use a rule `condition` in a `rule component` to make your Rule do some conditional logic or checks. What modules are you using?

Comment: Yeah it is that logic that I need help with. I am using the simplenews module to generate the newsletter which I have a template for. Other then that I am just using Views, Rules, and Rules Scheduler.

Comment: [Rules Bonus Pack](https://www.drupal.org/project/rb) has a Rules condition _Check number of results from a view_.